# I keep getting an parseException for having Unparseable date?

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-14

```
@Override
public OrderModel loadOrder(int orderID) {
    OrderModel order = null;
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM 'Order' WHERE OrderID = " + orderID);
        if (rs.next()) {
            order = new OrderModel();
            order.orderID = rs.getInt(1);
            "order.orderDate = rs.getDate(2);"
            order.customer = rs.getString(3);
            order.totalCost = rs.getDouble (4);
            order.totalTax = rs.getDouble(5);

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return order;

}
```

I keep getting this error when ever i try to load this info from my data base. Does anybody have a idea on what might be causing this. It says the line that I put in the quotation marks is the problem.

Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2005-25-06" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)

Comment: What is type of order.orderDate ?

Comment: The type is Date

Answer (score 0):

You are using the terribly flawed `java.sql.Date` class. That class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Use `LocalDate` instead when retrieving from a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Also, be sure the database column is of the correct data type rather than a textual type such as `VARCHAR`.